# Does Ubuntu have any comic/anime/manga/series about it?

Tags: community

As some communities have their own Comic, Manga, Anime, TV Series, does Ubuntu have one related to it, to the developers, the Ubuntu scenario or something related to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [Ubunchu](http://divajutta.com/doctormo/ubunchu/), which is about three high school students in a club getting started with Ubuntu. It claims to be the world's first Japanese Ubuntu manga translated into English.

EDIT: Here is a [direct link](http://seotch.wordpress.com/ubunchu/) to the "official" site for the series, which links back to the other page for translations.

Comment: Voted as accepted but if you find any other updated sites it would be nice to know. Maybe some Naruto/Bleach version of Ubuntu. You never know when nine tail demons might pop from Ubuntu or some powerful spirit sword might open the eyes of unworthy windows users ^^.